# Can anyone help me with reading a continuously updating video file with python?

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-streaming, video-processing

I have a small ImageAI program which is detecting a few objects via my webcam and/or IP webcam,
the final part looks something like this:

```
execution_path = os.getcwd()
detector = VideoObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path , "yolo.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
print('Model loaded')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

video_path = detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(camera_input=cap,
                        output_file_path=os.path.join(execution_path, "captured")
                        , frames_per_second=5, log_progress=True, detection_timeout=120)

print(video_path)
```

This is resulting in creating an avi file that is recording the video and detecting the objects.
While I can see the progress by opening this file, I have to close it and open again in order to see the ongoing updated progress.
Is there a way to display this video with something like %matplotlib inline, etc?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used it, but if you [look at the documentation](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/video/) it has an optional parameter to return the detected frame:

> **– parameter return_detected_frame (optional)** : This parameter allows
>   you to return the detected frame as a Numpy array at every frame,
>   second and minute of the video detected. The returned Numpy array will
>   be parsed into the respective per_frame_function, per_second_function
>   and per_minute_function (See details below)

and then you need to also pass a function to this parameter:

> **—parameter per_frame_function (optional ) :** This parameter allows you
>   to parse in the name of a function you define. Then, for every frame
>   of the video that is detected, the function will be parsed into the
>   parameter will be executed and and analytical data of the video will
>   be parsed into the function. The data returned can be visualized or
>   saved in a NoSQL database for future processing and visualization.

The new function should look like the one in the documentation:

```
def forFrame(frame_number, output_array, output_count, returned_frame):

    plt.clf()

    this_colors = []
    labels = []
    sizes = []

    counter = 0

    for eachItem in output_count:
        counter += 1
        labels.append(eachItem + " = " + str(output_count[eachItem]))
        sizes.append(output_count[eachItem])
        this_colors.append(color_index[eachItem])

    global resized

    if (resized == False):
        manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
        manager.resize(width=1000, height=500)
        resized = True

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.title("Frame : " + str(frame_number))
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.imshow(returned_frame, interpolation="none")

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.title("Analysis: " + str(frame_number))
    plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=this_colors, shadow=True, startangle=140, autopct="%1.1f%%")

    plt.pause(0.01)
```

This will also plot a the other analytical data, but you can just plot the frame.

Your code will have to change to look like this:

```
video_path = detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(camera_input=cap,
                        output_file_path=os.path.join(execution_path, "captured")
                        , frames_per_second=5, log_progress=True, detection_timeout=120,
                        return_detected_frame=True, per_frame_function=forFrame)
```

Take note of the two last arguments.

I hope this helps you

Comment: Well, I can't believe the answer was right before my eyes. This is working for me. Thanks a lot!! I think as a beginner, I should really start reading long lines of codes carefully. Thanks again. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @RiteshKankonkar no problem, the best way to start solving this kind of problems, is to look in the documentation if there is already an intended way :) If this helps you, please accept the answer, this way others would find the answer faster.